# splashscreen is different in simulator and device

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad

I got a splash  screen as Default.png this works on the simulator but when i debug my app on the ipad device itself, i get an old Default.png which does not exist anymore.
why is the splash screen different in the simulator and the device?

Comment: Try removing the app from the iPad and then doing a clean in Xcode (menu Product -> Clean). See if that works.

Comment: U might want to check whether the name is spelled exactly the same.  The iPad is case sensitive, so any discrepancy in the png file name could cause it to load an old file.

Comment: i dont have the option Product in the menu..=\(i got Xcode 3.2)

Comment: In Xcode 3 it may be Project -> Clean, I'm not sure. You can always go to the Help menu and type Clean in the search box. :)

Comment: I cleaned it , and i even deleted the whole build folder, but still it loads a different image on the device and a different on the simulator :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have had this problem before, the way i fixed it was cleaning the project, deleting the app off of the device, turn off the device, restart it and then try again.

If that doesnt work check all your images, it could still be holding a reference to the old one somewhere.